# SPARQL- Is there a way to only get the most recent population value in a Wikidata entity?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Im currently using a query that searches through cities/municipalities that have a population over 2000 people that looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?native ?cityLabel ?country ?countryLabel  ?population 
WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?settlement
  FILTER(?settlement = wd:Q515 || ?settlement = wd:Q15284)    
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country . FILTER (?country=wd:Q32)
  OPTIONAL{?city wdt:P1705 ?native }.

  FILTER(?population > 2000)
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```

The problem is that the population class is really inconsistent and Im filtering out stuff I actually want because its using the population from the 19th century for example. ([Like here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q16050))

Is there a way to only filter the most recent population value?